# Class object display 'class object at ...'

Tags: python, class

I'm wondering that when creating a class in python, for example, a class Car,
with the attributes being the make and year of the car, can return the name and the make,
without using anything except for

```
>>> c = Car('Toyota Camry', 2007)
>>> c
```

instead of returning `<car object at 0x0000000003394FD0>`

is there anyway to just return a tuple of

```
('Toyota Camry', 2007)
```

without implementing a `__str__` method in the car class?

Comment: Yes, overload `__repr__`.

Comment: **Why** don’t you want to use the solution which is *designed* to solve your problem?!

Comment: Vague test question made me paranoid and I couldn't find the solution :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd implement a [`__repr__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__); it is that method that is used when representing an object:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, make, year):
        self.make = make
        self.year = year

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Car({!r}, {!r})'.format(self.make, self.year)
```

This produces a representation string that looks just like the original class invocation:

```
>>> class Car:
...     def __init__(self, make, year):
...         self.make = make
...         self.year = year
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'Car({!r}, {!r})'.format(self.make, self.year)
... 
>>> Car('Toyota Camry', 2007)
Car('Toyota Camry', 2007)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) instead of `__str__`.

`__repr__` **represents** the objuect, while `__str__` is only called with a `print()`.

To do that, use the following:

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self, model, year):
        self.model = model
        self.year = year

    def __repr__(self):
        return str((self.model, self.year))
```

This will run as:

```
>>> camry = Car('Toyota Camry', 2006)
>>> camry
('Toyota Camry', 2006)
>>>
```